# How does the aura boon work with instantaneous duration boons?

Tags: healing, open-legend, boons

The *Aura* boon says:

> Choose a single bane or boon which uses the same attribute that you
>   used to invoke Aura. The maximum power level for the chosen bane or
>   boon is one-half the power level of your aura.

The duration for aura is 'Sustain Persists', meaning that it only continues you use a minor action each turn to keep it active.

However, heal has a duration of 'instantaneous', so regularly healing only applies once. Would it apply multiple times if was used with aura?

It gets even more confusing when the regeneration boon is introduced, as that has a duration of 'sustain persists' and has an effect like heal, so it would be pretty useless as an aura if an aura of healing worked multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Some DMs only allow *sustain persist* for aura

Some allows boons with instantaneous duration to work with aura. So you must consult your GM whether aura of healing works or not. One interesting point is that aura boon description gives circle of healing, not regeneration, as its example.

> You surround a willing target in an aura that hurts their foes or helps their allies. A shield of gamma radiation that burns attackers, **a circle of healing**, and an aura of elemental protection are all examples of this boon in action.

### How they work?

The description of aura boon says:

> The target and all allies **who end their turn** within the area of the aura automatically gain the chosen boon.

- heal boon: they gain hit points at the end of **their** turn
- regeneration boon: they gain regeneration boon at the end of their turn. They will gain hit points at the start of **the invoker's** turn

Other than they work different mechanically, aura of healing also heals you *more* than regeneration (**PL3:** 1d8 vs 1d6, **PL9:** 3d10 vs 2d6).

Overall, aura of healing is far stronger than aura of regeneration, but not all GM allows aura of healing (and other instantaneous boon), so consult your GM.